# Angular 9 - import font name and font url from database

Tags: html, css, angular

In database, I have font name and font url and that are data that can be changed by user from UI.

In my angular application, I should get that data from API and store it in css so my application would run with that selected font.

I was trying to parse custom variable to styles.css as I do for, example, button color but in this case it won't work.

Can you please assist me?

Comment: Generically, once you load the CSS data, you should be able to somehow access your apps root tag and apply the styles there through script.  You might want to look at renderer2 https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 set style or set class methods.  Apply them in your main app's component.

Comment: How can I access to css variable from app's component in that case? I will get font url on some button click after app's component will be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complete Example** :

This is my **NodeJs** Server :

Here I have 2 google fonts

```
const fonts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: `Quicksand`,
        url: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: `Anton`,
        url: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton'
    }
]

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(fonts)
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT : ${PORT}`)
})
```

**In Angular Client :**

I create a font class :

```
export class Font {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public url: string;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
  fonts$: Observable<Font>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fonts$ = this.http.get<Font>('http://localhost:3000')
  }

  applyFontToBody(font: Font) {
    const id = `font-${font.name}-${font.id}`;

    if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
      let style = document.createElement('link');
      style.setAttribute('href', font.url);
      style.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
      style.setAttribute('id', id)
      document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
    
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = font.name;
  }
```

app.component.html

```
 <div class="border p-4">
    <h5>
      In App Component
    </h5>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum consectetur enim, natus sed dicta modi nemo
    </p>
  </div>

  <ng-container *ngIf="(this.fonts$ | async) as fonts">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Url</td>
          <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of this.fonts; let idx=index">
          <td>{{idx+1}}</td>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.url}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="applyFontToBody(item)" type="button">
              Apply To Body
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: I should run that from which component?

Comment: In every component, you can do that because you are applying the font to the body ,

Comment: I tried but no changes on frontend. Is there a chance to set up directly in index.html but not to hardcode?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz  ? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: It is huge app for stackblitz preview :\

Comment: When I run this and inspect element, I can se that "font family" has been set properly but nothing hapens on UI, like "import" or "source" is not good.

Comment: Now when I think, even when I hardcoded @font-face with string values it doesn't work. Is problem maybe b cuz I call url from google api not from assets (I don't have fonts there)?

Comment: I will make an example for you and send it to you (with node js and angular) 10 hours later. thanks in advance

Comment: I created an example and it works perfectly 
then 
I updated my answer,  if you did not get the result, send your email address to me to send the Angular and NodeJs Project to you. good luck my friend

Comment: here you can download the project(client-server) - this link will be valid until 72 hours later- http://uupload.ir/filelink/JIqBKwF0UZD5/pz8b_font-url.zip

Comment: Wowww....now is working like a charm !:)) Thank you very much mate, I really appriciate your will for help! :))
Can you please give me info, why this works with "link" but it didn't work with @font-face?